# Use of align for multiple alignments needing right-alignment

Tags: align

I am currently having issues with the display of this equation below.

The code I have inserted is using `align` but I have also tried using `eqnarray`, (which has right-alignment but is deprecated), and am now at the point of considering using a table.

The alignment here doesn't appear to do as the documentation says, and when I add extra &'s I can get the format slightly better but not exactly as I want. To be clear, it is the right-alignment of the second column that is giving me most trouble.

Code:

```
\begin{align*}
&\frac{2^{1+k/2}}{k!} &< 1\\
\Leftrightarrow &2^{1+k/2} &< k!\\
\Leftrightarrow& (\sqrt{2})^k\cdot 2 &< \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k \sqrt{2 \pi k}
\end{align*}
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following is the appropriate way to have multiple alignments within an `align`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
% Original
\begin{align*}
 & \frac{2^{1+k/2}}{k!} & < 1\\
\Leftrightarrow & 2^{1+k/2} & < k!\\
\Leftrightarrow & (\sqrt{2})^k\cdot 2 & < \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k \sqrt{2 \pi k}
\end{align*}
% Correct
\begin{align*}
 && \frac{2^{1+k/2}}{k!} & < 1\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2^{1+k/2} & < k!\\
\Leftrightarrow && (\sqrt{2})^k\cdot 2 & < \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k \sqrt{2 \pi k}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As reference for multiple points within `align`, see the [`amsmath` user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **3.6 Equation groups with mutual alignment**, p 6-7). There's also other `align`-related environments that would yield this output, including `alignat`.

Regarding your venture to other environments, perhaps [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764) is of interest.

Comment: Great info, thanks very much for this as well as editing my original post